# How to translate "one of the ends" of a list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

It is said that Eno is in a cinema where there are 4 seats. Eno is seated at one of the ends.

What I would like to know is how I can translate the "one of the ends" into a code.

Here, the 4 seats is a List P with a length of 4.
What I tried is using **nth1**:

one_of_the_end(ListP, Eno):- nth1(1, ListP, Eno);nth1(4, ListP, Eno).

However it doesn't work.

Could you help me ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by saying "it doesn't work". How does it deviate from what you expected ?

Answer (score 1):

Since *Eno* is the name of a specific person and not a variable, you should represent it in Prolog as `eno` (or if you prefer, 'Eno'). So a simple solution is as follows:

```
eno_at_one_end([eno, _, _, _]).
eno_at_one_end([_, _, _, eno]).
```

Examples:

```
?- eno_at_one_end([ann, bob, coy, eno]).
true.

?- eno_at_one_end([ann, bob, eno, coy]).
false.

?- eno_at_one_end([ann, eno, bob, coy]).
false.

?- eno_at_one_end([eno, ann, bob, coy]).
true .

?- eno_at_one_end([ann, bob, coy, dan]).
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can express in swi-prolog as e.g.:

```
?- length(Seats, 4), (Seats = [Eno|_] ; last(Seats, Eno)).
Seats = [Eno,_,_,_] ;
Seats = [_,_,_,Eno].
```

or

```
?- length(Seats, 4), member(Pos, [1, 4]), nth1(Pos, Seats, Eno).
Seats = [Eno,_,_,_],
Pos = 1 ;
Seats = [_,_,_,Eno],
Pos = 4.
```